# Azure user deletion error

Tags: powershell, azure, office365

I am getting error "Could not delete user 'me@user.com'." in Azure and Office 365 error "Not all selected users were deleted Some users couldn't be deleted at this time. Correlation ID: ".

I have run the following with several O365 techs and it just won't delete. It is not in any shared resource, contact list, dlist, etc.

```
PS C:\Users\owner> set-executionpolicy unrestricted

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the execution
policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

PS C:\Users\owner> $Cred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

PS C:\Users\owner> Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName me@user.com

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Remove-MsolUser : Unable to complete this action. Try again later.
At line:1 char:16
+ Remove-MsolUser <<<<  -UserPrincipalName me@user.com
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Remove-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InternalServiceException,Microsoft.Online.Adm
   inistration.Automation.RemoveUser

PS C:\Users\owner> remove-msoldomain -domainname user.com -force
Remove-MsolDomain : Unable to remove this domain. Use Get-MsolUser -DomainName <domain name>  to retrieve a list of obj
ects that are blocking removal.
At line:1 char:18
+ remove-msoldomain <<<<  -domainname user.com -force
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Remove-MsolDomain], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DomainNotEmptyException,Microsoft.Online.Admi
   nistration.Automation.RemoveDomain

PS C:\Users\owner> get-msoluser -domainname user.com

UserPrincipalName                       DisplayName                             isLicensed
-----------------                       -----------                             ----------
me@user.com                     User A. Name                         False


PS C:\Users\owner> remove-msoluser -userprincipalname me@user.com

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Remove-MsolUser : Unable to complete this action. Try again later.
At line:1 char:16
+ remove-msoluser <<<<  -userprincipalname me@user.com
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Remove-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InternalServiceException,Microsoft.Online.Adm
   inistration.Automation.RemoveUser

PS C:\Users\owner> remove-msoluser -userprincipalname me@user.com -force
Remove-MsolUser : Unable to complete this action. Try again later.
At line:1 char:16
+ remove-msoluser <<<<  -userprincipalname me@user.com -force
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Remove-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InternalServiceException,Microsoft.Online.Adm
   inistration.Automation.RemoveUser
```

Comment: I'm sure this was already asked, but just to cover all bases: you aren't trying to delete the user you're signed in as, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try (in order):

1. Remove all licenses from the user using `Set-MsolUserLicense`
2. Change the domain of the user to a different domain:

   `$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "user.com"`

   `Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -NewUserPrincipalName "me@user.onmicrosoft.com"`

First try (1), then try to delete. If it still doesn't work, do (2), then try to delete.